# setting a variable from a file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sh

Is there a way to set a variable from a file in the docker compose?

The following does not work in compose (however it does if you attach to the container):

```
version: '2'
services:
  foo:
    image: busybox
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
          echo "hello" > id #this file will be supplied by a volume-from
          ls
          cat id
          TEST=$(cat id)   #This line does not work
          echo TEST
```

The error which is produced is:

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service "foo":
```

Comment: Docker compose allows env_file and environment keywords. Is this what you want? [Reference docs. ](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#env_file)

Comment: Why have you tagged `bash`?  You appear to be using `/bin/sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664673/how-to-get-port-of-docker-compose-from-env-file/52664919#52664919

Comment: @cdarke i try an use sh instead of bash as not all distro's have bash (alpine uses ash), but they all tend to support sh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I escape a $ dollar sign in a docker compose file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619582/how-can-i-escape-a-dollar-sign-in-a-docker-compose-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change a bit your config file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  foo:
    image: busybox
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
          echo "hello" > id 
          ls
          cat id
          TEST=$$(cat id)
          echo TEST
```

I checked against Docker Version `Docker version 18.06.0-ce` and Docker compose version `docker-compose version 1.20.0-rc2,`

https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/compose/compose-file/index.md#variable-substitution

> You can use a $$ (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a
>   literal dollar sign. This also prevents Compose from interpolating a
>   value, so a $$ allows you to refer to environment variables that you
>   don’t want processed by Compose.

Comment: Of course `echo TEST` still prints just the literal text `TEST`.  You want `echo "$$TEST"`