# Environment property not injected to volume mapping

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I run docker-compose up in a parent directory and -f the docker-compose.yml in child folder. Does anyone know why this won't work? MY_VAR is evaluated to empty string

```
root-ui-e2e-ci:
    environment: 
      MY_VAR: ./hello
    env_file: ./.env
    volumes:
        - ${MY_VAR}:/app
```

I end up with this error

> .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric
>   characters

Comment: could you please post your `hello` file

Comment: hello is a string, it will not work either with quote or no quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable specified in `environment` & `env_file` not used for compose-file, it will directly pass to container.

For variable substitution in `docker-compose.yaml`, you could use next two solutions, and use `docker-compose config` to quick check the effect:

**Solution 1:**

Use the variable export in the same shell which run `docker-compose`:

*docker-compose.yaml:*

```
version: '3'
services:
  root-ui-e2e-ci:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
        - ${MY_VAR}:/app
```

*Try Command:*

```
$export MY_VAR=./hello
$docker-compose config
services:
  root-ui-e2e-ci:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
    - /home/shubuntu1/99/hello:/app:rw
version: '3.0'
```

**Solution 2:**

Use `.env`:

Set a `.env` file in the same folder of `docker-compose.yaml`:

*.env:*

```
MY_VAR=./hello
```

*docker-compose.yaml:*

```
version: '3'
services:
  root-ui-e2e-ci:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
        - ${MY_VAR}:/app
```

*Try Command:*

```
$unset MY_VAR
$docker-compose config
services:
  root-ui-e2e-ci:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
    - /home/shubuntu1/99/hello:/app:rw
version: '3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

depends on you comment that `hello is a string`you need to rewrite you `docker-compose` like this:

```
environment:
  MY_VAR: hello
volumes:
  - ../${MY_VAR}:/app
```

Comment: still receive it as blank string

Comment: But the MY_VAR is still empty :(

Comment: it evaluate to ../ so it still maps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664673/how-to-get-port-of-docker-compose-from-env-file 
looks like environment property was read when building volume, i have to put it in .env specifically