# Docker compose shows Invalid port error when I set ports as env variables

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple docker-compose file which starts my spring boot application.

```
version: '3'
services:
  applic:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: local.Dockerfile
      args:
        - DEBUG_PORT=${DEBUG_PORT}
        - DEBUG_FLAG=${DEBUG_FLAG}
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local"
      - "DEBUG_PORT=5005"
      - "DEBUG_FLAG=true"
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - $DEBUG_PORT:$DEBUG_PORT
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - "../:/mnt"
```

when I start it with `docker-compose up --build` command it shows me this error:

```
applic.ports is invalid: Invalid port ":", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
```

What did I do wrong? I tried many solutions from the Internet, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change that to:

```
"${DEBUG_PORT}:${DEBUG_PORT}"
```

and this :

```
args:
        - DEBUG_PORT=${DEBUG_PORT}
        - DEBUG_FLAG=${DEBUG_FLAG}
```

to work you need to export them at first.

```
export DEBUG_PORT=xxxx && export DEBUG_FLAG=xxxx && docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: Looks like it works. But is it the only solution for this situation? I mean what if I don't want to enable debug? I should add export DEBUG_PORT even if I don't need this mode.

Comment: yes I think, because compose will always try to evaluate `"${DEBUG_PORT}:${DEBUG_PORT}"` and if this not set then it will see only `:`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the error from variable expansion at starting container.

```
   ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "${DEBUG_PORT}:${DEBUG_PORT}"
```

create .env at the root of your compose file.

```
DEBUG_PORT=80
```

According to [How to get port of docker-compose from env_file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664673/how-to-get-port-of-docker-compose-from-env-file) question you need to define `DEBUG_PORT` in `.env`.

> The `env_file` optin will only set environment variables in the docker
>   container itself. Not on the host which is used during the compose
>   'build'.
>
> To define your port as env var you should use the `.env` file as
>   described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)
>
> In your case create a .env file which contains::
>
> `DEBUG_PORT=5000`

Comment: Doesn't work( I tried to add env file to my docker-compose file but it shows me the same error.

Comment: you need place double qoutes as mentioned by linpy "     `"${DEBUG_PORT}:${DEBUG_PORT}"`

Comment: yes. I placed it as mentioned in the answer: - "${DEBUG_PORT}:${DEBUG_PORT}" and I added this param to local.env DEBUG_PORT=5005. I connected this file with docker-compose using this env_file: - local.env, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you check the link provided

Comment: docker-compose -f local/docker-compose-local.yml up --build

Comment: try to start docker-compose up --build from  local/ directory the `.env` must be in the working directory as compose.yml

Comment: `env $(cat .env) docker-compose -f local/docker-compose-local.yml up --build`