# docker-compose not read vars from env_file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with my docker-compose.yml and when try to up the services:

- My env is:
- docker 24.x
- docker-compose 2.22.x

based on this thread [How to get port of docker-compose from env_file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664673/how-to-get-port-of-docker-compose-from-env-file) i create my yml file, that looks like:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  django:
    image: my-django:production
    build:
      context: .
      target: production_build
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env.prod
    ports:
      - "${DJANGO_PORT_DOCKER}"
```

but then i run docker-compose up i got a WARN that dont let me continue:

```
    WARN[0000] The "DJANGO_PORT_DOCKER" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'ports': No port specified: <empty>
```

I want to add that this happens in certains machines, but i dont know why in other machines this works, any idea?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `env_file` only provides env inside the container itself.

Consider it like two boxes. On your machine you run `docker-compose` in the big box. Inside that box is a smaller box, inside which your container is running. `env_file` makes env available in the small box, but not the big box, which is where you are trying to access `DJANGO_PORT_DOCKER`.

To make this work you need something like `DJANGO_PORT_DOCKER=... docker-compose up` or `dotenv` or some other way to set the variable in your process.